Knobs but the fasteners are not with them. What are fasteners? Came w/tiny screws
I know these baby screws cannot go through a dresser. What are they even for? And what is a fasteber? New to this.thr[![screwtop


what is a fastener? anything that is used to hold something in place, nail, screw, staple, tape, glue, etc. etc.

Presumably the screw is just too short.  Go to a hardware store, bring the screw, use their tool to determine screw diameter and thread pitch.  Buy screw with same, but long enough to go through your drawer.
